# update libssl.so.1.1 for the LATEST version

Tags: bash, updates, 22.04, openssl

There is a known problem with downloading libssl.so.1.1 - you need to download it manually from some a separate repository.

Common solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72133316/libssl-so-1-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory

```bash
wget http://nz2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.17_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.17_amd64.deb
```

or from here: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/

The problem is that this is the second time I've been getting a version change (now actual 2.18), while the old one disappears from the site and how to figure out which one is the latest is not clear for me (unlike working with github tags/releases).

Updating this manually is a VERY bad option, I have a bunch of docker files, I don't have the strength for it anymore.

Maybe someone has sh-practices for downloading the latest version of the application from this kind of site?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If you have a bunch of docker files, why don't you have this downloaded into some persistent cache already, from where you can copy this for the image build process? Why are you downloading it again and again?

Comment: Package `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.18_amd64.deb` looks newer. But I am still curious why this package was removed from new releases of Ubuntu, while there are still so many legacy applications using it. And this library is included in the `core20` snap too: `ls -ald $(find /snap -name libssl.so.1.1 2>/dev/null)`

Comment: Please use edit and add new info to the question and not as comments.

Comment: @muru - the problem is that I don't make cache for the "htop" utility for n dockerfiles where I load it. I just say `apt-get install htop` and I get the latest version - that's it.

I'm interested here in a normal way to download the latest version and only.

Comment: No, the problem is that you're trying to do something *abnormal* (installing some package from a previous release into a newer release), so the solution is going to be abnormal. Your problem would be solved if you vendored this dependency properly, like any sane engineer would have if they couldn't eliminate it in the first place. Otherwise you're just leaving yourself open to the possibility of this being broken again in some other way. People who have n dockerfiles usually learn to use caching and vendoring for small values of n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to write a small parser that outputs a string with the latest version. But maybe someone has a more "correct/clean" way?

```bash
curl --silent GET http://nz2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/ | grep -o '="libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu[^>]*\_amd64.deb' | grep -o '1ubuntu.*' | sed -E 's/^1ubuntu//' | sed -E 's/_amd64.deb$//' | sort --numeric-sort | tail -1
```